# Using CSS column-count does not balance the content in Chrome only

Tags: css, google-chrome, multiple-columns

I have a catalogue page that lists stories in a catalogue and I'd like to display them across 3 columns. I'd like the output to be balanced across the three columns so that each column is approximately the same height. The items are not all of the same height each.

However I am finding that Chrome does not balance across the columns correctly and so the first two columns are very long and the last (3rd) columns is very short with usually none, 1 or two items only. I have added the attribute

```
column-fill: balance;
```

to be sure, even though it should be the default, but it makes no difference. Any help appreciated.

**CSS**

```
#catalogue-section  {
/* Prevent vertical gaps */
line-height: 0;

-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap:   0px;
-webkit-column-fill: balance;
-moz-column-count:    3;
-moz-column-gap:      0px;
-moz-column-fill: balance;
column-count:         3;
column-gap:           0px;
column-fill:balance;

}

#catalogue-section div {
/* Just in case there are inline attributes */
width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important; 
}
```

**HTML**

See http://www.shortkidstories.com/story

If you go to this page in IE or Firefox it balances the columns, but not in Chrome.

Comment: The columns are balancing fine for me, in chrome. MAC Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101

Comment: Tested in both FF 28.0 and Chrome 34.0 , Chrome results are actually better. EDIT : Oh when you scroll down, 3rd column remains empty for 2-3 items in Chrome

Comment: I'm using 34.0.1847.116m and it's not working consistently for me. As the items are presented in random order you might find different results, but in the main most are unbalanced. If the first one works then page to page 2 or 3 you'll see what I mean.

Comment: No other brainwaves anyone? Am still having the same issue all the time with Chrome and it's really bugging me!

Comment: I found the problem! I was using Animate.js to fly in the items from 4 different directions. I found that if you fly items in from below using Animate.js then it screws up the multi-column balancing - but on Chrome only! That's a pretty esoteric bug. Still, it was an easy fix just to remove that effect. Thanks for looking into guys.

Comment: @BrianM You can post your solution as an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The OP found the problem.  He was using Animate.js to fly in the items from 4 different directions. He found that if you fly items in from below using Animate.js then it screws up the multi-column balancing - but on Chrome only!

(Posted only to let other people know that was solved)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution:

- Remove `height: auto !important;` from `#catalogue-section div`
- Then add more height to `div.catalogue`, e.g., `min-height: 322px;`
- Inspect and adjust accordingly.